# Short wrapper for fetch (similar to axios)

Tags: javascript, performance, http

I was looking to replace my use of axios with just fetch, but I didn't like how verbose fetch was with regard to handling JSON output (having to have a separate `then` call just to return the json). Unfortunately calling `text()` first to see if it's a JSON response and then only calling `json()` if so seems wasteful because it first has to parse the response as text. If you have a large response payload (as I do in several cases) then double parsing seems inefficient.

So this isn't as complex as it could be because I only really need something simple. All of my requests are prefixed with `/api/` except one that has to call AWS, so I used `startsWith` for that case. Also, the only time I call `PUT` in the entire application is when I need to update an AWS resource.

```
  initializeRequestFactory = () => {
    const prefix = "/api/";

    let thenFunction = response => {
      // only time response isn't from app server is when it's from AWS
      // avoid expensive text() call in general case
      let data = response.ok && response.url.startsWith("https://s3") ? response.text() : response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        return data.then(json => {
          return { data: json, response: response };
        }).catch(err => {
          return { response: response };
        });
      } else {
        return { response: response };
      }
    };

    window.request = {
      get: url => {
        let theUrl = url.startsWith("http") ? url : prefix + url;

        return fetch(theUrl, {
          method: "GET",
          credentials: 'include',
          headers: {
            'sseid': window.globals.sseid
          }
        }).then(thenFunction);
      },
      post: (url, body) => {
        let theUrl = url.startsWith("http") ? url : prefix + url;

        return fetch(theUrl, {
          method: "POST",
          credentials: 'include',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'sseid': window.globals.sseid
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }).then(thenFunction);
      }, 
      put: (url, body, config) => {
        let theUrl = url.startsWith("http") ? url : prefix + url;

        return fetch(theUrl, {
          method: "PUT",
          credentials: 'omit',
          headers: config.headers,
          body: body
        }).then(thenFunction);
      }
    };
  }
```

I generally call it like this:

```
window.request.post("reply-to-thread", {
  thread_id: this.props.data.thread_id
});

window.request.get("get-my-profile").then(response => {
  this.setState({ profile: response.data });
});
```

It all seems to work but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas for improvements. Thanks for reading!